# Is this concatenation ({a} · {b})^2 ≠ a^2 · b^2?

Tags: formal-languages

I presumed they were equal, such that both resulted in `aabb`. However, I'm told they are false and I don't know why.

Is it because in the **second** one, we would concatenate `a · b` before raising to the power of 2, thus resulting in `abababab`? Or because in the **first** one you concatenate first, thus resulting in `abab`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Taking parentheses to precede every operator, what do you use for precedence between concatenation and repetition? (You can use $L^AT_EX$: `$(\{a\}\cdot\{b\})^2\ne\{a\}^2\cdot\{b\}^2$` yields $(\{a\}\cdot\{b\})^2\ne\{a\}^2\cdot\{b\}^2$ - some advise not to use it in question titles.)

Comment: (Just how do you generate the eight literals in `abababab`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different, because:

$(a \cdot b)^2 = abab$, since you need to concatenate $a$ and $b$ first, them reapeat the concatenation two times.

$a^2 \cdot b^2 = aabb$, since you need to concatenate the repetition of two $a$ with the repetition of two $b$.

Comment: Thank you. I guess different rules apply than those in Maths to numbers, or I might just be lost haha. Cheers!

Comment: @pixozerr You are welcome! The rules are "different" because concatenation is not multiplication and repetition is not exponentiation.